# Calculate car movement and distance with C++ classes

Tags: c++

This program compiles however, I need to get this function to move on the x & y coordinate and then output the total distance traveled. The xCord moves it right and left while the yCord moves it up and down. I think I need to update my int Taxicab::getDistanceTraveled(), void Taxicab::moveX(int getX),  & void Taxicab::moveX(int getX). But for the life of me can't figure out what to do to get it to update properly. When I compile and run it gives me 132617596 for cab1 distance travelled and 0 for the Y coordinate on cab2. Thanks for the help!

```
#ifndef TAXI_CPP
#define TAXI_CPP

class Taxicab
{
private:
    int xCord;
    int yCord;
    int totalDist;
public:
    Taxicab(); //default constructor
    Taxicab(int, int); //overload constructor
    int getX(); //returns X coordinate
    int getY(); //returns Y coordinate
    int getDistanceTraveled(); //returns distance calculation
    void moveX(int); //moves X left or right
    void moveY(int); //moves Y left or right 
};
#endif // !TAXI_CPP




#include "Taxi.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::abs;

Taxicab::Taxicab() //default constructor
{

}

Taxicab::Taxicab(int xCord, int yCord) //overload constructor
{
    xCord = 0; //initialize to 0
    yCord = 0; //initialize to 0
    totalDist = 0; //initialize to 0
}

int Taxicab::getX()
{
    return xCord; //return x coordinate
}

int Taxicab::getY()
{
    return yCord; //return y coordinate
}

void Taxicab::moveX(int getX)
{
    int moveX = 0;
    moveX = moveX + getX;
}

void Taxicab::moveY(int getY)
{
    int moveY = 0;
    moveY = moveY + getY;
}

int Taxicab::getDistanceTraveled()
{
    return abs(xCord) + abs(yCord);
}


#include <iostream>
#include "Taxi.h"
#include <math.h>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    Taxicab cab1;
    Taxicab cab2(5, -8);
    cab1.moveX(3);
    cab1.moveY(-4);
    cab1.moveX(-1);
    cout << cab1.getDistanceTraveled() << endl;
    cab2.moveY(7);
    cout << cab2.getY() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger allows you to execute statements one at a time and watch values of variables.  Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructors do not make sense.
In default constructor you have to initialize member variables to something, otherwise their values are undefined and could be set to some random value. Try these maybe:

```
Taxicab::Taxicab() //default constructor
{
    xCord = 0; //initialize to 0
    yCord = 0; //initialize to 0
    totalDist = 0; //initialize to 0
}

Taxicab::Taxicab(int xCord, int yCord) //overload constructor
{
    this->xCord = xCord;
    this->yCord = yCord;
    totalDist = 0; //initialize to 0
}
```

Methods to move taxi also do not make much sense. Maybe something like that would be better:

```
void Taxicab::moveX(int offsetX)
{
    totalDist += abs(offsetX);
    xCoord += offsetX;
}

void Taxicab::moveY(int offsetY)
{
    totalDist += abs(offsetY);
    yCoord += offsetY;
}

int Taxicab::getDistanceTraveled()
{
    return totalDist;
}
```

Comment: edited your answer a little. there was no moveX / moveY variable, it's xCoord, yCoord in the class, and it should just be abs(getX) as it's relative movement.

Comment: @JasonLang it's a bit not clear from the questions what should be the distance: if you move car 3 times to `moveX(1)` should the distance traveled to be 3 or 1? I think it should be 1, as 2nd and 3rd calls don't move it, as it's already at `xCord=1`

Comment: Ah, if it's offset not actual pos then yes, it makes sense.

Comment: If you do moveX(1) 3 times it would be 3, the moveX & moveY functions are supposed to be cause the taxi car to move every time they are run in the main function.

Comment: @Timk10 yes, I updated it to move 3 times by 1x if you call `moveX(1)`

Comment: just to note: we can glean that he did mean relative movement because his moveX function was originally structured as x = x + dx, the variable names weren't right, but the intent was to *add* the parameter to x